# How To connect to remote server via PHP

Tags: php, ssh2

I am trying to connect to my SSH Server via PHP.

I know I can easily connect to my ssh server via python using the [parimako](http://www.paramiko.org/) library. But at this time I need to do it using PHP

My Server Details:

```
ip: xx.xxxx.xxx  -Username:root  -Password: xxx12333
```

it doesn't work using shell_exec()

[source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFgd2CjUtko](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3CpS.jpg)

My question is, **How to connect to my ssh server and execute the command using php?**

**Appreciate any explanation.**

Comment: A simple Google on **php connect to ssh** Will show you, probably as the first link, [The PHP Manual for SSH2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php) We are not here to do your research for you

Comment: There is also a great open source library that wraps SSH for you that I'd recommend looking into: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html

Comment: Thank You Very Much!  I found the solution I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution
[Phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html) isn't working for me

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('ip.22.222.2', 22);

if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'pass')) {
  echo "Authentication Successful!\n";
} else {
  die('Authentication Failed...');
}
?>
```

**Replace The user/pass/IP with your own values**